# Why can't I declare a variable that takes the value of a dereferenced variable in Assembly?

Tags: assembly, nasm

In assembly(x86 NASM), it is perfectly okay to do this

```
a dd 17h
a2 dd a
```

with these 2 lines of code in the data segment I declare a doubleword `a`, to which I assign the value `17h`. Then I declare another doubleword and I give this doubleword the value of the address of a. This works and I understand what's going on.

But when I try to do this:

```
a dd 17h
a2 dd [a]
```

I get a syntax error! And I don't really know why. I expected this piece of code to define a doubleword `a` with the value `17h` (this is the same as in the previous example) and then define a doubleword `a2` that takes the value of `a`, so `17h`. But as I said, this doesn't seem to work. I am confused why this wouldn't work. From what I know, we can address memory as long as we follow the address offset formula which is in the form of **[base + index * scale + constant]**. In my case, the address of `a` a is constant so that will be the constant from the formula, and the base and scale will be zero. At least this is how I thought about it. But clearly, it doesn't work.

Comment: That only works in an instruction. `dd` is an assembler directive. Granted, your assembler could still process that but since it's compile time, you have no registers so the best you can do is a constant which is kind of pointless.

Comment: In order to dereference that value, the assembler would have to read from memory to get that value at runtime.  It cannot and should not make the assumption that the value won't change.

Comment: If you want the same value twice, use `times 2 dd 17h`.  Or define a macro for it that you use in both locations.  You can't reference the operand of a `dd` as an assemble-time constant even if it comes right after a label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But as I said, this doesn't seem to work. I am confused why this wouldn't work.

Simply because the assembler program doesn`t support it, although they could.

> From what I know, we can address memory as long as we follow the address offset formula which is in the form of [base + index * scale + constant]

Yes, that`s Intel syntax to express the addressing possibilities of x86 CPUs. However, that only applies at runtime, when the chip is doing the actual addressing.

What you are asking for is that the assembler program supports a similar syntax for defining data in your source file that takes the value of another definition. They could definitely do something like that (or not), but that's up to the designer of the assembler program. It's nothing to do with x86 addressing possibilities.